# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when migrating to Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, cocoapods

I have to migrate a project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3. In this application there is also Objective C parts. So far I experienced several issues, but this one is really giving me a hard time: I updated all the Swift 3 libraries accordingly, and now I get an error in one library that is primarily being used in the Objective C part, which i don't know much of.

I run into this build issue:

```
ld: framework not found CocoaLumberjack
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my pod file:

```
target 'SmartSpaces' do
xcodeproj 'SmartSpaces/SmartSpaces.xcodeproj'
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git'
pod 'Fingertips'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.2'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.26'    end

 post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
if target.to_s == 'RestKit'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] = '$(inherited) -framework "CocoaLumberjack"'
        end
    end
end
```

Does anybody know how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ld+framework+not+found+pod

Comment: Sorry, none of the suggested solutions in that post worked for me. Do you maybe have another idea?